# Stationary and Static

Tags: general-relativity

I have some confusion about the concept of stationary and static.

A metric $g$ is called **stationary** if there is a time like Killing vector $K$.

$g$ is called **static** is further HSO (hyper surface orthogonal), i.e. there exists a foliation of hyper surface orthogonal to the integral curve of $K$.

The Schwarzschild solution requires $g$ to be static, and the Kerr solution only require $g$ to be stationary.

Here comes my question. To my understanding, requiring $K$ to be HSO is to enabling us to slice the spacetime into pieces with fixed time. The Kerr solution is for the metric outside a rotating body. In the note I am reading, it says

> Do not require $K$ to be HSO, after all we want a rotating body.

Why a rotating body indicates that the metric cannot be HSO? I think I can also slice the spacetime into piece for every time.

Comment: You can slice the Kerr spacetime into constant $t$ slices, but the Killing vector $\partial /\partial t$is not orthogonal to those slices since there is a $dt\, d\varphi$ term in the Kerr metric.

Comment: Frobenius theorem.